# Is there AzMan 64bit?

Tags: c#, .net, azman

Is there 64 bit version of AzMan?

We have an app that uses Microsoft.Interop.Security.AzRoles.dll.Is there a 64 version of this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about Windows 7 as I don't have a box to check but as far as Server 2008 R2 goes, the answer you're looking for is here: [Where is microsoft.interop.security.azroles on Server 2008 R2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726594/where-is-microsoft-interop-security-azroles-on-server-2008-r2)  (but to save you clicking, it's in the GAC in 32-bit and 64-bit forms).

Answer (score 1):

On my Windows 7 machine, the files `azman.msc` and `azroles.dll` are present in both System32 and SysWOW64, which indicates that both 32-bit and 64-bit AzMan are supported, at least on Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: do you know if there is a Microsoft.Interop.Security.AzRoles.dll x64?