# Where is microsoft.interop.security.azroles on Server 2008 R2?

Tags: .net, security, azman

As far as I can recall, on Server 2003, microsoft.interop.security.azroles used to live in "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\authman".  On Server 2008 R2, that folder is empty.

Anyone know where it's hiding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, myself.  They've put it back in the GAC, in both 32-bit and 64-bit flavours:

```
gacutil /l Microsoft.Interop.Security.AzRoles
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
Microsoft.Interop.Security.AzRoles, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=AMD64
Microsoft.Interop.Security.AzRoles, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=x86

Number of items = 2
```

Comment: Would be nice if there was an MSIL version

Answer (score 0):

I found a copy in a subfolder of C:\Windows\winsxs. I have SQL Server 2008 loaded on this box.